# How to load a report definition from a non-absolute path?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

Here's a code that works

```
string connection = "Server=.\\sqlexpress;Database=dataSet_CrystalReport;Integrated Security=True;";
SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection(connection);
string select = "SELECT * FROM tblAccountDetails";
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(select, Con);
DataSet dst = new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(dst, "tblAccountDetails");
crystalRep.Load(@"C:\Users\Boss\Desktop\dataCrystalReport_Experiment\dataCrystalReport_Experiment\CrystalReport1.rpt");
crystalRep.SetDataSource(dst);
crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = crystalRep;
```

What I want is this code to work:

```
string connection = "Server=.\\sqlexpress;Database=dataSet_CrystalReport;Integrated Security=True;";
SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection(connection);
string select = "SELECT * FROM tblAccountDetails";
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(select, Con);
DataSet dst = new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(dst, "tblAccountDetails");
string filename = Path.GetFullPath("CrystalReport1.rpt");
crystalRep.Load(filename);                                // <-- Difference!
crystalRep.SetDataSource(dst);
crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = crystalRep;
```

The string filename is equivalent to the first code that works.
It has a path like this:

> C:\Users\Boss\Desktop\dataCrystalReport_Experiment\dataCrystalReport_Experiment\CrystalReport1.rpt

I dont know why it fails to load the report?

Comment: Do you have a more descriptive error, like an exception?

Comment: i dont have an exception sir, just load report failed...

Comment: Is this happening for the same user on the same machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Path.GetFullPath` method doesn't 'just' find the file for you in any place. Depending on the working directory of your application this might work or not. (in this case the file has to be in the working directory to let the call work)

Usually, you provide `Path.GetFullPath` with a relative file name and the method returns the full file name for you.

Include the report in Visual Studio and tell it to copy it to the output directory. Then you can reference it with only the file name. No path required.

Comment: crystalRep.Load(@"C:\Users\Boss\Desktop\dataCrystalReport_Experiment\dataCrystalReport_Experiment\CrystalReport1.rpt");
this code only works at my computer
but what if i run it to a different computer i think the path
would change and would result to an error.
What should i do so that it would be compatible to any computer

Comment: Include the report in Visual Studio and tell it to copy it to the output directory. Then you can reference it with only the file name. No path required.

Comment: thank you very much for the response Sir Patrick, Ok so I Add the crystal report in the Visual studio and Call it like this crystalRep.Load(Properties.Resources.CrystalReport1); , but i got an error when i try this,,, or im doing it wrong . please enlighten me sir

Comment: @user3699069: Just as a reminder: If your question was answered , please don't forget to mark the question answered by checking the checkmark before the answer you liked most.